# File is not deleted when file path is generated dynamically

Tags: java, file, spring-boot

I am facing a problem but have not able to solve it yet. Let me share what I have done till now. I tried to delete a file using `java.nio.file` packages. And below is my code.

```
// directory will be dynamically generated.
String directory = fileDirectory+ "//" + fileName;
Path path = Paths.get(directory);
if (Files.exists(path)) {
    Files.delete(path);
}
```

I generated the path correctly. But when `Files.exists(path)` calls it `return false`. That's why file is not deleted. But if I generated the `directory string` by hard-coded than it works perfectly.

```
// hard-coded directory works perfectly.
String directory = "C://opt//tomcat//webapps//resources//images//sprite.jpg";
```

I also tried the another method `Files.deleteIfExists(path);`. Which check the both the file existence and delete the file.

The other packages `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` and `java.io.File` have tried. But can't resolve the issue.

**Note:** My application is in `spring-boot`. And I read the directory from the `application.properties` file for both save images and delete images.

**EDIT:**

> file uploading I mean save into the directory is perfectly worked. But file deletion does not work.

`application.properties`

```
image.root.dir=images
image.root.save.dir=C:/opt/tomcat/webapps/resources/
```

in implementation file

```
@Value("${image.root.dir}")
private String UPLOADED_FOLDER;

@Value("${image.root.save.dir}")
private String saveDir;

String directory = saveDir + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/" + fileName;
```

**save file into directory**

```
String directory = saveDir + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/";
try {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Path path = Paths.get(directory);
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        Files.createDirectories(path);
    }
    path = Paths.get(directory, file.getOriginalFilename());
    Files.write(path, bytes);
} catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("save image into directory : " + e);
}
```

Comment: If the target os is Linux based the file separator should be "/" and if it is windows it should be "\\", you have used" //".

Comment: @Op What is the target os?

Comment: thank you. My PC is windows and the My server is linux. And one information I like to share that is `path variable` print the `formatted String` whatever I used '//' it converted to as os convenient. from server log I get '/' and local I get '\'. Thanks @Ran

Answer (score 0):

```
String directory = fileDirectory+ "//" + fileName;
```

This is not the correct separator used between a directory and a file name, though it seems to work as well.

This means the problem is not the separator, but a mismatch between the code that you use to generate the path and this code. You're generating the directory into somewhere else than where this is pointing.

Comment: Let me check your suggestion. But "//" is worked surprisingly.

Comment: @R.A.Munna yes, seems to indeed work. The problem has to be a mistmatch between your generating code and this one - please add the code you use to generate the path.

Comment: @R.A.Munna You can use `File.separator` to avoid such problems.

Comment: @Ran `/` will work regardless of the OS, `File.separator` is not needed. However, it doesn't seem separator is the problem here.

Comment: `/` has not work. I have also added the details of my code what I have done

Comment: @R.A.Munna you're still not showing the code how you save the file.

Comment: @eis, will you please check the edited Question as you suggested?.

Comment: @R.A.Munna ok, so you're saving to `saveDir + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/"`. Is that the same thing as `fileDirectory+ "//" + fileName`?

Comment: as your suggestion I changed "//" to "/". And both are working fine for file saving.

Comment: yes, that's expected. but is `saveDir + UPLOADED_FOLDER + "/"` you use for saving the same thing as `fileDirectory+"/"+fileName` used for deleting?